# Run method on another thread android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have an object that implements runnable. This object is my gameview, where the world of the game is processed.

Gameview is owned by another class: Game. Game is handling the UI for the gameView, so it is running on the ui-thread.

When the user touches something it is caught by the UI-thread. This is because if the user touches perhaps a skill-icon i need to pass data about what skill it was to the gameView.

My issue is that quite get:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.Vector$Itr.checkForComodification(Vector.java:1193)
at java.util.Vector$Itr.next(Vector.java:1145)
at com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller.RenderSystem.render(RenderSystem.java:55)
at com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller.GameView.run(GameView.java:90)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

When touching the screen. I suspect it is because the method in GameView is still running on the UI thread, not the thread in the gameview.

To clarify here is the method in game (that is running on the UI-thread):
Where the third argument in gameView.touch would be the skill id (currently set to -1)

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                gameView.touch(x,y, -1);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

gamview.Touch:

```
public void touch(int screenX, int screenY, int skillId) {
    int worldX = renderSystem.screenToWorldX(screenX);
    int worldY = renderSystem.screenToWorldY(screenY);

    renderSystem.clear();
    if (map[worldX][worldY] != 1) {
        ArrayList<Point> route = calculateRoute(new Point(0,0), new Point(worldX,worldY));
        for (Point p : route) {
            renderSystem.addSprite(R.drawable.guy, p.x, p.y);
        }
    }
```

(Currently only removing every sprite on the screen and adds new sprites)

When the crash occurs, the log refers to the run method in gameView:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int frameSkipped = 0;
            //update();
            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawARGB(255,65,65,65);
                renderSystem.render(canvas); <---------- CRASH HERE
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            long updateTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - updateTime);

            if (sleepTime > 0) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = MAX_FPS;
                    msg.what = UPDATE_FPS;
                    handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

            while (sleepTime < 0 && frameSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = 1000 / updateTime;
                msg.what = UPDATE_FPS;
                handler.dispatchMessage(msg);

               // update();
                sleepTime+=FRAME_PERIOD;
                frameSkipped++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the issue is that the run method and touch method in GameView is running on different threads but i cant say for certain. How do i make it so that gameView.touch is running on the same thread as gameView.run?

Edit: formated code.

Edit: So to clarify further, i have one thread that's iterating the vector and one that tries to remove items in it. How do i make it so that the thread that removes items in the vector runs on the same thread as the one that iterates over it?

Comment: Your primary issue is that you have many threads trying to touch your Vector while you are iterating, or accessing otherwise.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have one thread that's iterating the vector and one that tries to remove items in it. How do i make it so that the thread that removes items in the vector runs on the same thread as the one that iterates over it?

Comment: Have you tried marked the methods as synchronized, or wrapping the access in synchronized blocks?

Comment: Threading isn't the issue. Vectors are threading safe, but that doesn't mean that you can iterate and remove at the "same time", from any two threads You've not added the full render method, so it's hard to tell